# Show/Hide footer on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide, show

Im trying to make a footer fully showing in the bottom once I scroll.

https://teste.contahl.com/

It is working on desktop, but not in mobile, can someone help me with?

Tkx

CSS---

```
footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100vw;
    transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

JS---

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("footer").style.bottom = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("footer").style.bottom = "-5vh";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Comment: This works fine in the mobile-simulation mode with FF. This works with chrome (both desktop, desktop in mobile simulation mode and on the android device) with some glitches (but still works). What device are testing this on?

Comment: Hi, I was testing on a iPhone 13 mini. For some reason it seems ok here. Thank you

Comment: You might find IntersectionObserver useful.